# Where can I find decent resolution (5m ish) night time orthophotography/satellite imagery data for Ireland?

Tags: raster, satellite, aerial-photography, orthophoto

Anything I've found so far has been incredibly granular. I need a resolution which is fine enough to see general lighting footprints for motorway junctions.